# LINQ Query returns false when it should be true

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following LINQ query written by a former developer and it isn't working when it should.

```
        public bool IsAvailable(Appointment appointment)
    {
        var appointments = _appointmentRepository.Get;
        var shifts = _scheduleRepository.Get;
        var city = _customerRepository.Find(appointment.CustomerId).City ?? appointment.Customer.City;

        const int durationHour = 1;

        DateTime scheduledEndDate = appointment.ScheduledTime.Add(new TimeSpan(durationHour, 0, 0));

        var inWorkingHours = shifts
            .Where(x =>
                //Check if any available working hours
                x.Employee.City == city &&

                x.ShiftStart <= appointment.ScheduledTime &&

                x.ShiftEnd >= scheduledEndDate &&

                //check if not booked yet
                !appointments
                    .Where(a =>
                        (appointment.Id == 0 || a.Id != appointment.Id) &&
                        a.Employee.Id == x.Employee.Id &&
                        (
                            (a.ScheduledTime <= appointment.ScheduledTime &&
                             appointment.ScheduledTime <= EntityFunctions.AddHours(a.ScheduledTime, durationHour)) ||
                            (a.ScheduledTime <= scheduledEndDate &&
                             scheduledEndDate <= EntityFunctions.AddHours(a.ScheduledTime, durationHour))
                            ))
                    .Select(a => a.Employee.Id)
                    .Contains(x.Employee.Id)

            );

        if (inWorkingHours.Any())
        {
            var assignedEmployee = inWorkingHours.FirstOrDefault().Employee;
            appointment.EmployeeId = assignedEmployee.Id;
            appointment.Employee = assignedEmployee;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

CLASSES

```
    public class Appointment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledTime { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fullname { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }

    public Customer(){ }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fullname { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }

    public Employee() { }
}

public class Shift
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime ShiftStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftEnd { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

The query is suppose to handle the following scenarios

1. Given An Appointment With A ScheduledTime Between A ShiftStart and ShiftEnd time But Does not match any employees in same city - (Return true)
2. Given An Appointment With A ScheduledTime Between A ShiftStart and ShiftEnd time AND Employee for that shift is in the same city as the customer (Return True AND Assign to the employee)

If the customer is NOT in the same city as an employee we assign the appointment as "Unassigned" as along as the scheduledTime is within an of the employees shift start/end times

If the customer is in the same city as an employee we assign the appointment to one of the employees (firstOrdefault) and occupy that timeslot.

Appointments CAN NOT overlap (Assigned Ones). Unassigned can't overlap each other.

This query use to work (I've been told). But now it doesn't and I have tried refactoring it and various other paths with no luck. I am now on week two and just don't know where the issue in the query is or how to write it.

Let me know if I need to post anything further. I have verified appointments, shifts, city all populate with valid data so the issue doesn't appear to be with null or missing data.

Comment: Something that helps when posting questions like this, is including a basic definition of the other types involved in this code. Employee, Appointment, City, etc.

Comment: Should I add the domain classes for Employee, Appointment? Repository class is a wrapper for Entity Framework it's generic).

Comment: yes, I can see at least Employee, Appointment, Shift, City types, plus EntityFunctions.AddHours method that you haven't provided, and for the sake of brevity and relevance, you can omit members that are not used in the code.

Comment: [EntityFunctions.AddHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.addhours.aspx)

Comment: @RJLohan is there anything else you want to see? I apologize in advance I am missing things.

Comment: I would have broken that into several smaller and simpler linq queries, so you can actually see what's happening, and ease the maintainability of the code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is not 100% clear what do you mean by "This query use to work (I've been told). But now it doesn't". Could you please provide some cases which show how it "doesn't work"?

From my point of view the query looks almost right, but I guess there are some strange things. Let's look on this piece of code:

```
!appointments
    .Where(a =>
        (appointment.Id == 0 || a.Id != appointment.Id) &&
        a.Employee.Id == x.Employee.Id &&
        (
            (a.ScheduledTime <= appointment.ScheduledTime &&
            appointment.ScheduledTime <= EntityFunctions.AddHours(a.ScheduledTime, durationHour)) ||
            (a.ScheduledTime <= scheduledEndDate &&
            scheduledEndDate <= EntityFunctions.AddHours(a.ScheduledTime, durationHour))
         ))
    .Select(a => a.Employee.Id)
    .Contains(x.Employee.Id)
```

In the WHERE condition besides everything else you filter by the `a.Employee.Id == x.Employee.Id`. It means that the collection after the WHERE clause will contain only appointments of the single employee. So I guess we can rewrite this part to:

```
!appointments.Any(a =>
    (appointment.Id == 0 || a.Id != appointment.Id) &&
    a.Employee.Id == x.Employee.Id &&
    (
        (a.ScheduledTime <= appointment.ScheduledTime &&
        appointment.ScheduledTime <= EntityFunctions.AddHours(a.ScheduledTime, durationHour)) ||
        (a.ScheduledTime <= scheduledEndDate &&
        scheduledEndDate <= EntityFunctions.AddHours(a.ScheduledTime, durationHour))
     ))
```

Another issue that might be: comparing of start/end dates. In the code above you are checking the following:

```
.........[----------------]...........
               ^^^^^^
               ||||||
      start date and end date 
        not in this interval
```

So you check:

- that the start date (of new appointment) is not somewhere during an another appointment
- and the end date (of new appointment) is not somewhere during an another appointment

It means that you will not catch the following situation:

```
.........[----------------]...........
     ^                           ^    
     |                           |    
 start date                  end date
```

which is also unacceptable. But according to your code `const int durationHour = 1;`. So every meeting lasts for one hour and this braking situation should not be a problem for you.

Anyway, some kind of sample data where the code is braking down will be great.